# How to update yet inserted data on site, only after moderation?

Tags: php, mysql

Searching on google didn't help. And I decided to ask this here:

On our website, users have pages with his data, Name, Surname, Address ...

And users can change this data, but we want to approve the edit that they make and only after update the data publicly on the website.

From here two step:
1 - User change his data and see a preview.
2 - User approve and we review the request and decide update or not his data with new.

I think to copy all table that related to user and use the first copy for the website and the second copy for user edits, and want to hear what you suggest to me, I am using PHP and MySQL.

(Please sorry for a bad english, hope the problem is explained)

Comment: Yes i understood, for any problem, there are many solutions, i want to see the most quick, simple and beautiful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create table 'pending_changes' and have identical fields. On approve, move data over to original table.

There is a ghetto fix, create a field "pending_changes" make it text. encode data with json - json_encode(), thus you can parse them with json_decode(), once approved, empty the pending_changes cell and populate original fields.